# Problem compiling substrate node in WSL ( windows )

Tags: substrate-node-template

Getting `error: failed to run custom build command for` jemalloc-sys v0.3.2 error` when compiling substrate-node-template in wsl environment.

Comment: Try using wsl2 instead of wsl

Answer (score 2):

If you get this kinda error when compiling you substrate-node-template make sure you have all these installed

```bash
mrisholukamba@mrisholukamba:~$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/mrisholukamba/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)
--------------------------------------------
```

after that and it does not compile , make sure you install

```
apt-get install make
```

---

Note: This applies if the substrate-node-template is fresh
But after playing around with it and you get error when compiling then make sure you read the error message and tackle it accordingly. This problem occurred to me and it was wise sharing the solution to any beginner.