# Error: failed to run custom build command for `tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2`

Tags: substrate-node-template, cargo, wsl

I was trying to build the substrate-node-template (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/create-your-first-substrate-chain/) for the first time. I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I came to the step of  `cargo build --release` and I got the following error:

```
Compiling tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2
error: failed to run custom build command for `tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/mnt/c/Users/ggodf/Documents/Programming tests/Parachain project/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-fd6a5adda1344782/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  TARGET=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  HOST=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  NUM_JOBS=16
  OUT_DIR="/mnt/c/Users/ggodf/Documents/Programming tests/Parachain project/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-27a9467e997ef107/out"     
  BUILD_DIR="/mnt/c/Users/ggodf/Documents/Programming tests/Parachain project/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-27a9467e997ef107/out/build"
  SRC_DIR="/home/g/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tikv-jemalloc-sys-0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2"
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  CC="cc"
  CFLAGS="-O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64 -Wall"
  JEMALLOC_REPO_DIR="jemalloc"
  running: "sh" "/mnt/c/Users/ggodf/Documents/Programming tests/Parachain project/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-27a9467e997ef107/out/build/configure" "--disable-cxx" "--with-private-namespace=_rjem_" "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--prefix=/mnt/c/Users/ggodf/Documents/Programming tests/Parachain project/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-27a9467e997ef107/out"
```

I already tried the solutions proposed https://github.com/gnzlbg/jemallocator/issues/148 and https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_36941283/article/details/124361536 but no luck.

The issue has resulted in me not being able to proceed with the command ./target/release/node-template --dev because it fails and cannot find the directoy /node-template.

Thank you.

P.s first time stack exchange poster, please let me know if my formatting is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

[Problem compiling substrate node in WSL ( windows )](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/problem-compiling-substrate-node-in-wsl-windows)

Following solved the issue.

Was missing wasm32 as installation target.

Comment: Fixed in the docs now. Thanks for reporting, guthub is best to report errors like this though FYI, to get it fixed 