# Error: 'tikv-jemalloc-sys' fails to build after upgrading substrate-based chain on WSL2

Tags: error, cargo, build, wsl

After upgrading our chain and its relevant dependencies to polkadot-v0.9.22 I am getting the following build error for 'tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2' [image]

[image]

I have also tried to add `parity-util-mem = { version = "0.11", default-features = false, features = ["jemalloc-global"] }` as a dependency to our node's Cargo.toml file and it does not seem to solve the problem.

Here is my current rust configuration
[image]
I have tried applying the solutions suggested in  [Problem compiling substrate node in WSL ( windows )](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/problem-compiling-substrate-node-in-wsl-windows) and  [Error: failed to run custom build command for `tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/error-failed-to-run-custom-build-command-for-tikv-jemalloc-sys-v0-4-35-2-1-pa) but still seems to get the same error. Furthermore, the problem does not seem to occur on non-WSL machines

Comment: Just a quick test, can you compile the [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template)?

Comment: @bruno No, I get the same error as the one I mentioned in the post

Comment: I am assuming you have already ran `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt install --assume-yes git clang curl libssl-dev llvm libudev-dev make protobuf-compiler`, `cargo clean`, `cargo build`.

Also, worth noting that there is a [newer version](https://crates.io/crates/tikv-jemalloc-sys) of `tikv-jemalloc-sys`. You could try manually updating and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest available version of all of my system libraries + the mentioned ones are installed too. I will try to manual update ` tikv-jemalloc-sys ` @bruno , thanks for the  suggestion

Comment: Is this still an issue? Were you able to resolve it? If so, please share your answer.

Comment: @bruno yes it is still an issue. I have tried reinstalling substrate from scratch on a new WSL distro for both polkadot 0.9.22 and 0.9.24 and the issue still exists. I have also tried manually updating **tikv-jemalloc-sys**  on 0.9.22 but other dependencies required the version that causes build errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the given solutions worked for me.

Later when I had my whole directory in the WSL2 file system (instead of the windows file system like earlier) and tried the build command, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Got a similar issue when running builds on Ubuntu. Managed to resolve it by installing jemalloc via `sudo apt install libjemalloc2`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use command:
`sudo make install`